# Building QGIS 3 undeclared identifiers and classes on macOS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, compile

Has anyone had any luck building QGIS 3 on macOS?
I keep getting unkonwn type name errors when running it:

```
/Users/user/Downloads/QGIS-master/src/core/qgspointlocator.cpp:62:39:
error: unknown class name 'IDataStream'; did you mean 'QDataStream'?

/Users/user/Downloads/QGIS-master/src/core/qgspointlocator.cpp:40:8: 
error: no type named 'Region' in namespace 'SpatialIndex'; did you mean 'QRegion'?
static SpatialIndex::Region rect2region( const QgsRectangle &rect )
```

What is reponsible for rebinding `QPoint` to `Point` and `QDatastream` to `IDataStream`